# How to show inventory tab on etherscan

Tags: etherscan, erc-721

Sorry, i'm newbie about ERC-721. I have deployed my contract and verified it. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x677f76d276355c382da948d2476da06cf5dc6219

But I don't see inventory tabs like other tokens (crypto kitties, etc.). And I want  to display this tab.

[image]

Is this inventory tab related to metadata on the ERC-721 standard or is it automatically created? and then, what information can be displayed on this inventory tab? like the CryptoKitties token, I saw a token image, token id, and owner. But on other tokens only give a token id and owner.

[image]

Would someone explain to me? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the instructions at:
https://medium.com/etherscan-blog/tracking-erc-721-non-fungible-token-on-etherscan-b4da1ed955ed

Comment: It said "The API endpoint for retrieving the image URL" but doesn't provide a response format for the endpoint. Where can I look for it?